# code for finding the number of occurrences of the largest element in an array giving segmentation error

Tags: c++, function, c++11, vector

I am writing a function in c++ which takes a vector array as a parameter and then finds the number of occurrences of the largest value in it.
I have written function birthdaycakecandles and main function as below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int birthdaycakecandles(vector<int> a)
{
    int largest=a[0];
    int pos;
    for(int i=1;i<a.size();++i)
    {
        if(largest<a[i])
        {
            largest=a[i];
            pos=i;
        }
    }
    int count=1;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();++i)
    {
        if(a[i]==largest&&i!=pos)
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    double n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> a;
    for(double i=0;i<n;++i)
    cin>>a[i];
    int val=birthdaycakecandles(a);
    cout<<val;
    return 0;
}
```

Please review the code and suggest me the reason(s) for the error.
The compiler is giving me segmentation error.
Thanks.

Comment: `cin>>a[i];` is not how you fill a `vector`. You need a temporary variable and `push_back`. Either that or first fill the vector with default values and then you can overwrite those values

Comment: Alternatively, you could initialize the `vector<int> a` to the intended ful size: `vector<int> a(n);`.

Comment: @UnholySheep can you please give the solution using that way?

Comment: @Scheff please help with the solution

Comment: Both solutions are given in the answer below. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Given the code

```
vector<int> a;
for(double i=0;i<n;++i)
    cin>>a[i];
```

`a` is empty; access to nonexistent elements as `a[i]` leads to UB, anything is possible.

You can initialize `a` containing `n` elements from the beginning.

```
size_t n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> a(n);
for(size_t i=0;i<n;++i)
    cin>>a[i];
```

Or use `push_back` to insert elements into `a`.

```
size_t n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> a;
for(size_t i=0;i<n;++i) {
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    a.push_back(x);
}
```

PS: Using `double` as the index of `vector` seems meaningless.

Comment: _UB_ -> [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) - the most afraid of every C++ programmer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When using vector, we have to add elements using `push_back` or `emplace_back`. In order to traverse the vector, make use of vector iterators for exception safety due to out of bound access.

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin() ; it != a.end(); ++it)
{
    //your implementation goes here.
    cout << *it << endl; //access each element like this
}
```

Also note that a.end() is in fact the `last_element + 1`

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int> a;`
`for(double i=0;i<n;++i)`
`cin>>a[i];`
This is not the way to input in vector use a.push_back(i); instead;
and use auto to traverse till a.begin() till a.end()